# WP7 Reminder Object in Mango (7.1)

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've read several articles on how to setup demo Reminders and Alarms...  I'm interested in taking the Reminder idea 1 step further.  If I have a date in mind that I need the Reminder to be shown how would I accomplish this?

Right now I can set the reminder and prompt the user to snooze the reminder for up to 1 month.  But what I would really like to do is set the date for the user and then have the display to snooze the reminder if they want.

Is there documentation or blogs that demonstrate how to do that?  If not, anyone have any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% confident on what you're trying to achieve but the Reminder behaviour doesn't allow any customization of what is displayed to the user.
I'd suggest looking for a different method of notifying the user in a different way. Maybe create a separate calendar contiang the events/reminders which the user can subscribe too. I'd also consider using another method of reminding the user of these events (maybe an email or SMS).

Comment: Ideally I would like to add an item to their calendar, but from what I understand that isn't available either.  The reminder was a users suggestion and I'm just checking it out.  I could just as easily send out a timed e-mail as well.  Thanks as always.